# Get a delivery confirmation in java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a simple java mail code where I am trying to get a confirmation via an email or through any means possible of whether or not the email was delivered successfully, for now I have tried out the following code, the Email is sent fine, just that I am not able to get a delivery confirmation.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage;

import net.htmlparser.jericho.Source;

public class SmtpMail {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String to = "amit.jadhav@myorg.com"; //both emails are valid
        String from = "reciever@sample.com";
        String host = "relay.myorg.com";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "SMTP");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        SMTPMessage smtpMessage = new SMTPMessage(session);
        try {
            smtpMessage.setSender(new InternetAddress(from));
            smtpMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
            smtpMessage.setSubject("Hello Test Email");
            smtpMessage.setText("Test Email to check Delivery Report");
            smtpMessage.setReturnOption(SMTPMessage.RETURN_FULL);
            smtpMessage.setNotifyOptions(SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS);
            Transport.send(smtpMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while building smpt email");
        }

    }

}
```

Am I on the right track? Do I need to refer something else? I tried to learn more about Delivery Status Notification but so far have not been able to find a working example.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. Make sure that your smtp server supports Delivery Status Notification.

Sending an `EHLO` using telnet should be good enough; it should output DSN. Something like

```
[root@blah ~]$ telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 blah ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1; Fri, 28 Jun 2013 10:30:28 -0400; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
EHLO toto
250-blah Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

Comment: I tried this, and I did get the proper results, but my code does not return any notifications. In what way will the sender be notified for a successful delivery? Via an email? or by some other means?

Comment: I am facing the same scenario here, does anyone of you guys managed to get this delivery notification?